# C# send actions from 1 scope to another

Tags: c#, delegates, action, predicate

I couldn't find what I'm looking for, I tried different ways and none seems to work.

There is any way for this to work?

```
public class A
{
    public void B(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Executing B..");
    }
    public void C(Action action)
    {
        action();
        Console.WriteLine("Executing C..");
        action();
    }
}
    
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int z = 2;
    var a = new A();
    a.C(likePredicate => {
        likePredicate.B(z);
    });
}
```

The idea is to get the next result..

```
Executing B..
Executing B..
Executing C..
Executing B..
Executing B..
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it, this is the code to maintain the specific object in the lambda

```
public class A
{
    public void B(int num)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Executing B..");
    }
    public void C(Action<A> action)
    {
        action?.Invoke(this);
        Console.WriteLine("Executing C..");
        action?.Invoke(this);
    }
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int z = 2;
    var a = new A();
    a.C(e => {
        e.B(z);
    });
}
```

Thanks to @NotTheDr01ds to teach me how to properly answer my own question in other post and not editing my own.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**